# Flag formula field in Page Header based on results

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to flag a Y or N value in the page header if one or more specific values exist in the report result set. (Located in the details section)

It should check to see if `"16"` exists in the result set. I tried using a running total in the group footer, then setting the formula field in the header to display Y if the count is > 0. But the field only works on the page which contains the 16 in the details section. So if 16 only appears on Page 2, the Page 1 header will incorrectly say N. The field should be Y if 16 appears on *any* page.

SQL queries aren't possible in formula fields, so is there some way to make this work without one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place this formula "Has16" in your details section and suppress it:

```
{Table.Field} = "16"
```

Then place a second formula in your Page Header:

```
IF SUM({@Has16}) > 0 THEN "Y" ELSE "N"
```

This will display correctly even on pages that don't contain a 16.

Comment: That worked! Can I ask why it works when the count({@Has16}) is put in the details section but does not when put in the footer? Is the COUNT function counting the instances of "16" across the entire result set when placed in details vs only doing it per page when placed in footer?

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing. By putting Has16 into the details section, it's checking each individual entry for an instance of 16. Put it in the footer, and it only checks the *last* entry.

Comment: Got it! Didn't realize crystal was so flunky. Will keep it in mind for future reports. Thanks again.